# sed place parentheses at the beginning and close on the 4th line

Tags: linux, unix, sed

Im trying to place a open parenthesis on the first line and close it as the end of the 4th line. Below is a example of the data followed by the output that I am looking for.

```
tester1
SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
Thu Mar 19 23:27:57 UTC 2015
192.168.1.3
tester2
SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
Fri Mar 20 00:31:59 UTC 2015
192.168.1.2
```

```
(tester1
SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
Thu Mar 19 23:27:57 UTC 2015
192.168.1.3)
(tester2
SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
Fri Mar 20 00:31:59 UTC 2015
192.168.1.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do it as

```
awk 'NR%4==1{print "("$0; next} NR%4==0{print $0")"; next}1'
```

**Test**

```
$ awk 'NR%4==1{print "("$0; next} NR%4==0{print $0")"; next}1' input
(tester1
SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
Thu Mar 19 23:27:57 UTC 2015
192.168.1.3)
(tester2
SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
Fri Mar 20 00:31:59 UTC 2015
192.168.1.2)
```

**Shorter version**

```
awk 'NR%4==1{$0="("$0} NR%4==0{$0=$0")"}1'
```

Comment: Shorten some `awk 'NR%4==1{$0="("$0} NR%4==0{$0=$0")"}1'`

Comment: @Jotne That is pretty. Will add to answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/^/(/;N;N;N;s/$/)/' input
```

The `N` reads the next line into the buffer. `s/^/(/` puts an opening paren at the beginning, `s/$/)/` puts a closing one at the end of the buffer.