# sed add comma at end of every 4th line

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I need to add a comma to the end of every fourth line. here is a example of the output followed by what i am looking for.

```
("tester1",
"SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED",
"Thu Mar 19 23:27:57 UTC 2015",
"73.217.129.159")
("tester1",
"SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED",
"Fri Mar 20 00:31:59 UTC 2015",
"73.217.129.159")
```

And what I need

```
("tester1",
"SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED",
"Thu Mar 19 23:27:57 UTC 2015",
"73.217.129.159"),
("tester1",
"SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED",
"Fri Mar 20 00:31:59 UTC 2015",
"73.217.129.159"),
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do some reading about `sed`? You already asked three questions in the same context: [place paranthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29173589/344480), [remove comma](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29182026/344480), ...

Comment: your question is to add at 4th and in fact it is after a `)`, you need to be bit better in your request formulation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using awk

awk is well-suited to this:

```
$ awk '0==NR%4{$0=$0","} 1' file
("tester1",
"SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED",
"Thu Mar 19 23:27:57 UTC 2015",
"73.217.129.159"),
("tester1",
"SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED",
"Fri Mar 20 00:31:59 UTC 2015",
"73.217.129.159"),
```

How it works:

- `0==NR%4{$0=$0","}`

  NR is the line number.  `NR%4` is the line number modulo 4.  Thus, `0 == NR%4` on every fourth line.  For those lines, we add a comma at the end: `$0=$0","`.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

### Using sed

It looks like you want a comma after every line that ends with a close-parens.  If that is the case, then:

```
$ sed 's/)$/),/' file
("tester1",
"SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED",
"Thu Mar 19 23:27:57 UTC 2015",
"73.217.129.159"),
("tester1",
"SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED",
"Fri Mar 20 00:31:59 UTC 2015",
"73.217.129.159"),
```

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to add a comma after every closing ) then you can do the following:

```
sed 's/)$/),/'
```

This would accommodate records that differed in number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can just subtitute any ending ")" with ")," by using this sed command:

```
sed 's/)$/),/' <your file>
```